# Parameter Estimation for Gaussian Function in Gaussian noise

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

Mathematical model can be given as follows.

$$x[n]=a\exp[-(n - k)^2/s^2]+w[n]$$

Here w[n] is a zero mean Gaussian noise process with variance $3\cdot10^{-5}$. The problem is to estimate the parameters $a$, $k$ and $s$ as good as possible. The data samples are collected sequentially. Therefore, it is expected that the algorithm is capable of making estimations on the fly and the estimation quality improves with the increase of the total number of data samples.

I just started for the case where the noise is simply non-existence.

I used the following code, for the below given data and it works pretty well. The problem is when I add a littlle bit of noise to this data in order to simulate the above given mathematical model.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mydata[[1 ;; 300]], a*Exp[-(x - k)^2/s^2], {a, k, s}, x]
```

for example:

```
mydata2 = mydata + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[3*10^-5]], 400];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mydata2[[1 ;; 300]], a*Exp[-(x - k)^2/s^2], {a, k, s}, x]
```

or

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mydata2[[1 ;; 400]], a*Exp[-(x - k)^2/s^2], {a, k, s}, x]
```

both do not produce meaningful results.

> What must one do to be able to deal with this problem using NonlinearModelFit? Or in general for example with Maximum likelihood estimation (MLE)? I tried MLE but I cannot get anything in closed form except for the Amplitude a.

```
mydata={{1, 0.0004696016896143079`}, {2, 
0.0004754998605167475`}, {3, 0.00048146795030926896`}, {4, 
0.0004875067327344009`}, {5, 0.000493616989397984`}, {6, 
0.0004997995098406223`}, {7, 0.0005060550916096482`}, {8, 
0.0005123845403316832`}, {9, 0.0005187886697856992`}, {10, 
0.0005252683019766862`}, {11, 0.0005318242672098824`}, {12, 
0.0005384574041655253`}, {13, 0.0005451685599742198`}, {14, 
0.0005519585902928752`}, {15, 0.0005588283593811737`}, {16, 
0.0005657787401786761`}, {17, 0.0005728106143824625`}, {18, 
0.0005799248725254053`}, {19, 0.0005871224140549774`}, {20, 
0.0005944041474126807`}, {21, 0.0006017709901140973`}, {22, 
0.0006092238688294729`}, {23, 0.0006167637194649574`}, {24, 
0.0006243914872444208`}, {25, 0.0006321081267919121`}, {26, 
0.0006399146022146664`}, {27, 0.0006478118871867838`}, {28, 
0.0006558009650335242`}, {29, 0.0006638828288161673`}, {30, 
0.0006720584814175511`}, {31, 0.0006803289356282413`}, {32, 
0.0006886952142332748`}, {33, 0.0006971583500995931`}, {34, 
0.0007057193862640794`}, {35, 0.0007143793760222815`}, {36, 
0.0007231393830176956`}, {37, 0.0007320004813317731`}, {38, 
0.0007409637555745676`}, {39, 0.0007500303009759804`}, {40, 
0.0007592012234777229`}, {41, 0.0007684776398259019`}, {42, 
0.0007778606776643128`}, {43, 0.0007873514756283212`}, {44, 
0.0007969511834394849`}, {45, 0.0008066609620008387`}, {46, 
0.0008164819834928088`}, {47, 0.0008264154314698429`}, {48, 
0.0008364625009577514`}, {49, 0.0008466243985516465`}, {50, 
0.0008569023425146643`}, {51, 0.0008672975628773075`}, {52, 
0.0008778113015375558`}, {53, 0.0008884448123615773`}, {54, 
0.0008991993612852293`}, {55, 0.0009100762264162467`}, {56, 
0.000921076698137077`}, {57, 0.000932202079208501`}, {58, 
0.0009434536848739328`}, {59, 0.0009548328429644679`}, {60, 
0.000966340894004572`}, {61, 0.0009779791913185954`}, {62, 
0.0009897491011379713`}, {63, 0.0010016520027091057`}, {64, 
0.0010136892884020524`}, {65, 0.001025862363819943`}, {66, 
0.0010381726479090703`}, {67, 0.0010506215730697898`}, {68, 
0.0010632105852681447`}, {69, 0.001075941144148263`}, {70, 
0.0010888147231454353`}, {71, 0.0011018328096000214`}, {72, 
0.001114996904872117`}, {73, 0.0011283085244569028`}, {74, 
0.001141769198100848`}, {75, 0.0011553804699186276`}, {76, 
0.0011691438985108552`}, {77, 0.0011830610570825238`}, {78, 
0.0011971335335622672`}, {79, 0.0012113629307224428`}, {80, 
0.0012257508662998923`}, {81, 0.0012402989731175613`}, {82, 
0.0012550088992069328`}, {83, 0.0012698823079311588`}, {84, 
0.0012849208781090693`}, {85, 0.001300126304139942`}, {86, 
0.0013155002961291102`}, {87, 0.0013310445800143`}, {88, 
0.0013467608976928378`}, {89, 0.0013626510071496933`}, {90, 
0.0013787166825862166`}, {91, 0.0013949597145498226`}, {92, 
0.0014113819100643969`}, {93, 0.0014279850927616303`}, {94, 
0.0014447711030130214`}, {95, 0.0014617417980628403`}, {96, 
0.0014788990521619123`}, {97, 0.0014962447567021162`}, {98, 
0.0015137808203518409`}, {99, 0.0015315091691922803`}, {100, 
0.0015494317468544429`}, {101, 0.0015675505146571435`}, {102, 
0.0015858674517457525`}, {103, 0.0016043845552318901`}, {104, 
0.0016231038403338208`}, {105, 0.0016420273405178289`}, {106, 
0.0016611571076404561`}, {107, 0.0016804952120914654`}, {108, 
0.0017000437429378116`}, {109, 0.0017198048080683862`}, {110, 
0.0017397805343397233`}, {111, 0.001759973067722423`}, {112, 
0.001780384573448571`}, {113, 0.0018010172361600572`}, {114, 
0.0018218732600576001`}, {115, 0.0018429548690508228`}, {116, 
0.0018642643069091724`}, {117, 0.0018858038374136323`}, {118, 
0.0019075757445094173`}, {119, 0.0019295823324595143`}, {120, 
0.0019518259259991753`}, {121, 0.001974308870491162`}, {122, 
0.001997033532082018`}, {123, 0.0020200022978592415`}, {124, 
0.00204321757600922`}, {125, 0.0020666817959762093`}, {126, 
0.0020903974086221343`}, {127, 0.002114366886387389`}, {128, 
0.0021385927234523765`}, {129, 0.0021630774359001114`}, {130, 
0.0021878235618797226`}, {131, 0.002212833661770739`}, {132, 
0.0022381103183484164`}, {133, 0.0022636561369500053`}, {134, 
0.0022894737456417603`}, {135, 0.0023155657953870647`}, {136, 
0.0023419349602153542`}, {137, 0.0023685839373920855`}, {138, 
0.0023955154475894373`}, {139, 0.002422732235058113`}, {140, 
0.0024502370678000586`}, {141, 0.0024780327377419684`}, {142, 
0.0025061220609098843`}, {143, 0.002534507877604617`}, {144, 
0.00256319305257824`}, {145, 0.0025921804752112995`}, {146, 
0.0026214730596911488`}, {147, 0.0026510737451912337`}, {148, 
0.0026809854960511046`}, {149, 0.002711211301957591`}, {150, 
0.002741754178126894`}, {151, 0.002772617165487437`}, {152, 
0.002803803330863877`}, {153, 0.00283531576716194`}, {154, 
0.002867157593554324`}, {155, 0.002899331955667316`}, {156, 
0.0029318420257686026`}, {157, 0.002964691002955967`}, {158, 
0.002997882113346801`}, {159, 0.0030314186102687224`}, {160, 
0.003065303774451082`}, {161, 0.0030995409142175016`}, {162, 
0.00313413336567916`}, {163, 0.0031690844929292495`}, {164, 
0.003204397688238352`}, {165, 0.00324007637225061`}, {166, 
0.0032761239941810146`}, {167, 0.0033125440320136814`}, {168, 
0.0033493399927008493`}, {169, 0.0033865154123630826`}, {170, 
0.003424073856490291`}, {171, 0.0034620189201438464`}, {172, 
0.003500354228159393`}, {173, 0.0035390834353508653`}, {174, 
0.0035782102267154447`}, {175, 0.0036177383176392553`}, {176, 
0.0036576714541042455`}, {177, 0.003698013412895921`}, {178, 
0.0037387680018121402`}, {179, 0.0037799390598726064`}, {180, 
0.003821530457529599`}, {181, 0.0038635460968796066`}, {182, 
0.003905989911875701`}, {183, 0.003948865868541081`}, {184, 
0.003992177965183619`}, {185, 0.004035930232611049`}, {186, 
0.004080126734347439`}, {187, 0.004124771566850392`}, {188, 
0.00416986885972943`}, {189, 0.004215422775964974`}, {190, 
0.004261437512128586`}, {191, 0.004307917298604109`}, {192, 
0.00435486639980953`}, {193, 0.004402289114420054`}, {194, 
0.004450189775591967`}, {195, 0.00449857275118758`}, {196, 
0.004547442444000855`}, {197, 0.004596803291984207`}, {198, 
0.00464665976847628`}, {199, 0.004697016382430332`}, {200, 
0.004747877678643866`}, {201, 0.004799248237989198`}, {202, 
0.004851132677644647`}, {203, 0.004903535651326949`}, {204, 
0.004956461849524496`}, {205, 0.005009915999731568`}, {206, 
0.0050639028666832585`}, {207, 0.00511842725259155`}, {208, 
0.005173493997382378`}, {209, 0.005229107978933174`}, {210, 
0.005285274113311835`}, {211, 0.0053419973550162415`}, {212, 
0.005399282697215`}, {213, 0.005457135171988643`}, {214, 
0.005515559850572118`}, {215, 0.005574561843598148`}, {216, 
0.005634146301341157`}, {217, 0.005694318413962399`}, {218, 
0.005755083411756057`}, {219, 0.005816446565395737`}, {220, 
0.005878413186182366`}, {221, 0.005940988626292675`}, {222, 
0.006004178279028781`}, {223, 0.006067987579068253`}, {224, 
0.006132422002715424`}, {225, 0.006197487068153544`}, {226, 
0.0062631883356974215`}, {227, 0.0063295314080473175`}, {228, 
0.006396521930543493`}, {229, 0.006464165591421823`}, {230, 
0.0065324681220697645`}, {231, 0.006601435297283679`}, {232, 
0.0066710729355268766`}, {233, 0.006741386899188109`}, {234, 
0.006812383094841357`}, {235, 0.006884067473506359`}, {236, 
0.006956446030909557`}, {237, 0.0070295248077463105`}, {238, 
0.007103309889943699`}, {239, 0.007177807408924284`}, {240, 
0.007253023541870322`}, {241, 0.00732896451198904`}, {242, 
0.007405636588778868`}, {243, 0.007483046088295842`}, {244, 
0.007561199373421404`}, {245, 0.007640102854130552`}, {246, 
0.00771976298776116`}, {247, 0.007800186279283448`}, {248, 
0.007881379281570702`}, {249, 0.00796334859567074`}, {250, 
0.008046100871077617`}, {251, 0.008129642806004526`}, {252, 
0.008213981147657484`}, {253, 0.008299122692509127`}, {254, 
0.008385074286573856`}, {255, 0.00847184282568334`}, {256, 
0.008559435255762958`}, {257, 0.008647858573108479`}, {258, 
0.00873711982466387`}, {259, 0.008827226108299748`}, {260, 
0.008918184573092054`}, {261, 0.009010002419601842`}, {262, 
0.009102686900155536`}, {263, 0.009196245319125947`}, {264, 
0.009290685033213592`}, {265, 0.009386013451728938`}, {266, 
0.009482238036875396`}, {267, 0.009579366304032336`}, {268, 
0.009677405822039234`}, {269, 0.009776364213480477`}, {270, 
0.00987624915497003`}, {271, 0.009977068377437481`}, {272, 
0.010078829666414185`}, {273, 0.01018154086232032`}, {274, 
0.010285209860751873`}, {275, 0.01038984461276873`}, {276, 
0.010495453125183327`}, {277, 0.010602043460849177`}, {278, 
0.01070962373895057`}, {279, 0.010818202135292367`}, {280, 
0.010927786882590718`}, {281, 0.011038386270763546`}, {282, 
0.011150008647222046`}, {283, 0.011262662417162849`}, {284, 
0.011376356043859661`}, {285, 0.011491098048956299`}, {286, 
0.011606897012759966`}, {287, 0.011723761574534348`}, {288, 
0.011841700432793744`}, {289, 0.01196072234559729`}, {290, 
0.012080836130843974`}, {291, 0.012202050666567049`}, {292, 
0.012324374891229834`}, {293, 0.012447817804021589`}, {294, 
0.012572388465153093`}, {295, 0.012698095996153359`}, {296, 
0.012824949580166162`}, {297, 0.012952958462247309`}, {298, 
0.013082131949661404`}, {299, 0.013212479412179602`}, {300, 
0.013344010282377671`}, {301, 0.013476734055933404`}, {302, 
0.013610660291925196`}, {303, 0.013745798613130704`}, {304, 
0.013882158706325`}, {305, 0.014019750322579735`}, {306, 
0.014158583277561974`}, {307, 0.014298667451833773`}, {308, 
0.014440012791150826`}, {309, 0.014582629306762357`}, {310, 
0.014726527075710786`}, {311, 0.014871716241130982`}, {312, 
0.015018207012550263`}, {313, 0.015166009666188132`}, {314, 
0.015315134545256497`}, {315, 0.015465592060258998`}, {316, 
0.015617392689291267`}, {317, 0.01577054697834125`}, {318, 
0.015925065541588505`}, {319, 0.016080959061704408`}, {320, 
0.0162382382901525`}, {321, 0.016396914047487634`}, {322, 
0.016556997223656153`}, {323, 0.01671849877829549`}, {324, 
0.016881429741034147`}, {325, 0.01704580121179054`}, {326, 
0.0172116243610727`}, {327, 0.017378910430277787`}, {328, 
0.017547670731990553`}, {329, 0.017717916650282543`}, {330, 
0.017889659641010587`}, {331, 0.0180629112321157`}, {332, 
0.018237683023920606`}, {333, 0.018413986689427973`}, {334, 
0.018591833974618544`}, {335, 0.018771236698747706`}, {336, 
0.018952206754643035`}, {337, 0.019134756109001325`}, {338, 
0.019318896802684327`}, {339, 0.019504640951015263`}, {340, 
0.019692000744074168`}, {341, 0.019880988446993795`}, {342, 
0.02007161640025356`}, {343, 0.020263897019974386`}, {344, 
0.020457842798212975`}, {345, 0.02065346630325453`}, {346, 
0.020850780179906252`}, {347, 0.02104979714978936`}, {348, 
0.02125053001163171`}, {349, 0.02145299164155823`}, {350, 
0.021657194993382013`}, {351, 0.021863153098895007`}, {352, 
0.022070879068156565`}, {353, 0.02228038608978288`}, {354, 
0.022491687431235516`}, {355, 0.022704796439108162`}, {356, 
0.02291972653941392`}, {357, 0.023136491237871225`}, {358, 
0.023355104120189686`}, {359, 0.023575578852353802`}, {360, 
0.023797929180907142`}, {361, 0.024022168933235784`}, {362, 
0.024248312017849494`}, {363, 0.02447637242466357`}, {364, 
0.02470636422527892`}, {365, 0.024938301573262146`}, {366, 
0.025172198704423065`}, {367, 0.025408069937092777`}, {368, 
0.02564592967240078`}, {369, 0.025885792394549478`}, {370, 
0.026127672671089334`}, {371, 0.026371585153192822`}, {372, 
0.026617544575925807`}, {373, 0.026865565758519682`}, {374, 
0.027115663604641082`}, {375, 0.027367853102661762`}, {376, 
0.027622149325925435`}, {377, 0.02787856743301484`}, {378, 
0.028137122668018034`}, {379, 0.028397830360791194`}, {380, 
0.028660705927222665`}, {381, 0.028925764869493876`}, {382, 
0.029193022776340737`}, {383, 0.029462495323311303`}, {384, 
0.02973419827302401`}, {385, 0.030008147475424414`}, {386, 
0.030284358868038947`}, {387, 0.030562848476228626`}, {388, 
0.030843632413441655`}, {389, 0.031126726881462462`}, {390, 
0.03141214817066134`}, {391, 0.031699912660241324`}, {392, 
0.03199003681848457`}, {393, 0.03228253720299529`}, {394, 
0.03257743046094255`}, {395, 0.03287473332930184`}, {396, 
0.033174462635092716`}, {397, 0.03347663529561699`}, {398, 
0.03378126831869377`}, {399, 0.03408837880289416`}, {400, 
0.03439798393777186`}}
```

Comment: What is `t^2` in your code?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci t=1. Sorry. I am updating. It is actually unnecessary variable here.

Comment: I think  `w[n]` should be `w[n]=PDF[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[3*10^-5]], n]`,  no?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Sorry. It is wrong. It is not a pdf. It is just samples from the x axis of that PDF. In your comment you are taking the values of that PDF as w[n].

Comment: It work pretty good if you take `var=Sqrt[3*10^-8]` But this might be too low for your application..

Comment: I need variances even more than $3*10^{-5 }$ not less. This is actually the essence of this question..

Comment: Why don't you just use `aExp[sx]` as a model.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci because in my application, a Gaussian signal is coming in Gaussian noise. However, I do not know when it comes. So the parameter $k$ will tell me the location of the peak. This parameter is probably more important than the amplitude a. Because if I can know the variance and the mean values, I can just go back to signal and take the value of the signal at the location of the mean and this will give me the rough amplitude.

Comment: Would you share what values of `a`, `k`, and `s` that you used to generate the data?  Also, you added some random error to both the response and predictor variables when you should only add the random error to the response.  You should use `mydata2 = mydata;
mydata2[[All, 2]] = 
  mydata[[All, 2]] + 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[3*10^-5]], 400];`.  You'll also need to increase the `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` as the estimated mean square error is so small (relative to the `PrecisionGoal` and the `AccuracyGoal`.

Comment: @JimB You will get the correct values if you use mydata with the first 300 or more data. Then with those parameters you can also draw the true Gaussian curve.

Comment: I could really get the correct values if you would just state what they are.

Comment: @JimB a=3.874, k=1445, s=481

Comment: In general saying "[does] not produce meaningful results."  is a meaningless statement. With code it's important to know exactly _what_ is different from what you'd expect, _where_ that starts, and _how_ you know your expectation is correct.

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues:

1. You've added noise to the predictor variable when you just want to add noise to the response variable.
2. You don't give starting values for your parameters and the default value of "1" is very far away from two of the parameters.  That can cause any iterative fitting procedure (*R*, *SAS*, *Python*, *MATLAB*, or *Mathematica*) to fail.
3. You are not only increasing the sample size but you are also increasing the range of the predictor variable.  That's extremely important to get good (and not almost perfectly correlated) estimates of the parameters.

Given the parameters that generate the data consider the 400 points that you've shown vs 3000 points which would be a more complete coverage of the Gaussian-shaped curve you're trying to fit:

```
n = 3000;
mydata = Table[{x, a Exp[-(x - k)^2/s^2] /. {a -> 3.874, k -> 1445, s -> 481}}, {x, n}];
mydata2 = mydata;
SeedRandom[12345];
mydata2[[All, 2]] = mydata2[[All, 2]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[3 10^(-2)]], n];
ListPlot[{mydata2, mydata2[[1 ;; 400]]}]
```

[image: Data being used]

Essentially (given the parameter values you used) you are attempting to estimate all 3 parameters from just a tiny relatively linear part of the curve.  One can certainly predict the mean values in the first 400 observations very well but one can't expect to get good estimates of the individual parameters.

You would be much better off sampling less frequently but over a wider range of the predictor variable (irrespective of how much noise there is in the data).

So, in short, it's not a software problem but rather the expectation that one can get good estimates of the 3 parameters from just a small section of a curve with multiple parameters.

***Addition:***

`NonlinearModelFit` works fine when reasonable starting values are given:

```
(* Function to fit any contiguous subset of the data *)
nlm[n1_, n2_] := Module[{fit}, 
  fit = NonlinearModelFit[mydata2[[n1 ;; n2]], {a Exp[-(x - k)^2/s^2], a > 0 && s > 0},
        {{a, 4}, {k, 1500}, {s, 500}}, x];
  Print[fit["BestFitParameters"]];
  Print[fit["CorrelationMatrix"] // TableForm]; 
  Show[ListPlot[mydata2[[n1 ;; n2]]],
    Plot[fit[x], {x, n1, n2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}, PlotRange -> All]]]


nlm[1, 300]
(* {a->1168.61,k->7077.02,s->529.724} *)
```

[image: Parameter correlation matrix for n1=1 and n2=300]

[image: Fit for n1=1 and n2=300]

```
nlm[1, 3000]
(* {a->3.87959,k->1444.26,s->479.592} *)
```

[image: Parameter correlation matrix for n1=1 and n2=3000]

[image: Fit for n1=1 and n2=3000]

For just the first 300 data points there's not much curvature in the range of the predictor variable so the prediction is fine but the parameter estimates are highly correlated and certainly not very close to the actual values generating the data.  That's just a fact of life.

When all 3000 points are used, the fit is good and the parameter estimates are much less correlated with each other and are close to the actual values generating the data.

***2nd addition:***

To show what happens with a contiguous sub-segment of a sample of 3000 points, the following statements allows one to select a contiguous sub-segment and the approximate 95% confidence ellipse for `a` (maximum height) and `k` (time of maximum height) is plotted.  The confidence ellipse looks mostly like a line segment because the estimators for `a` and `k` are generally highly correlated.

```
n = 3000;
mydata = Table[{x, a Exp[-((x - k)/s)^2] /. {a -> 3.874, k -> 1445, s -> 481}}, {x, n}];
mydata2 = mydata;
SeedRandom[12345];
mydata2[[All, 2]] = mydata2[[All, 2]] + 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[3 10^(-2)]], n];

nlm[n1_, n2_, nn_] := 
 Module[{fit, aa, kk, ss, pci, ellipsoid}, 
  fit = Quiet[NonlinearModelFit[mydata2[[n1 ;; n2]], a Exp[-(x - k)^2/s^2], 
  {{a, 4}, {k, 1500}, {s, 500}}, x, MaxIterations -> 5000]];
  {aa, kk, ss} = {a, k, s} /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
  pci = fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervals"];
  cov = fit["CovarianceMatrix"][[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]];
  cov = {{cov[[2, 2]], cov[[1, 2]]}, {cov[[1, 2]], cov[[1, 1]]}};
  ellipsoid = 
   Ellipsoid[{kk, aa}, cov Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], 0.95]];
  Show[ListPlot[{mydata2, mydata2[[n1 ;; n2]]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 3000}, {Min[mydata[[All, 2]]] - 0.2, 
       1.5 Max[mydata[[All, 2]]]}}, PlotStyle -> {LightGray, Red}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, Epilog -> {Blue, Thin, ellipsoid}], 
   ListPlot[{{kk, aa}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.02]}], 
   Plot[fit[x], {x, n1, nn}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thin}, PlotRange -> All]]]

Manipulate[
 If[nStart + nPoints - 1 > 3000, nPoints = 3000 - nStart + 1];
 nlm[nStart, nStart + nPoints - 1, 3000], 
 {{nStart, 1, "Starting point"}, 1, 2950, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{nPoints, 1050, "Number of observations"}, 50, 2950, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {nStart, nPoints}]
```

[image: Example of predicting timing and height of peak]

Comment: Still not working. Just take all those 3000 points and make the variance $3*10^{-4}$ I can see by my eyes that there is a Gaussian curve and I can find the parameters by myself, yet I cannot find it with Mathematica. As I said the question is about finding solutions as good as possible under noise. So robust solutions are sought.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I don't get any useful result using your answer, still. Good lessons though. Where are the results of your answer?

Comment: You'll need to be specific about what "I don't get any useful result" means.

Comment: Could you please put the outputs of your suggested algorithm in your answer? What did you find? For which noise what parameters did you find? If we increase the total number of data from 400 to 3000 what are the results of your suggested method?

Comment: Sorry, still not sure what you mean.  For the first 300 points and the first 3,000 points I listed the parameter estimates:  `{a->1168.61,k->7077.02,s->529.724} ` and `{a->3.87959,k->1444.26,s->479.592}`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just looking for the results as you posted afterwards. Assume that you want to build a system to detected the Gaussian functions online. Each Gaussian has 3 parameters as above and they are embedded in a Gaussian noise. Then, how will you know that you chose the correct parameters? The system should automatically set its own parameters and work. One can still say that the amplitude a is say between 0.5 and 5 and the parameter k is say between 200 and 800. Any kind of Gussian peak can come, and we really dont know much about it, especially when it will come..

Comment: You are too optimistic.  You get estimates with estimated standard errors.  You don't ever get "the correct parameters".  I think you should consider giving more details about your objectives.  If indeed there is an underlying Gaussian curve, do you want to predict when the peak will occur?  How how the peak will be?  How long will it take for the curve to reach 20% of the maximum?  Maybe some description of how the data is really generated as opposed to a theoretical Gaussian-shaped model with Gaussian errors. Try asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I mean I dont need the parameters perfectly but as good as possible. The peaks are not known. There will be a Gaussian shaped thing over there coming at some random time and the task is to detect the parameters as good as possible. Noise profile is fixed but the amplitudes can vary so as the variance and the mean.. this is the complete problem definition. The variance of the noise is as given in the question. I may try stats. but I am not sure much about it.

Comment: I mean I dont need the parameters perfectly but as good as possible. The peaks are not known. There will be a Gaussian shaped thing over there coming at some random time and the task is to detect the parameters as good as possible. Noise profile is fixed but the amplitudes can vary so as the variance and the mean.. this is the complete problem definition. The variance of the noise is as given in the question. I may try stats. but I am not sure much about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98642/discussion-between-jimb-and-seyhmus-gungoren).